# Show JavaScript function once every 10 visits(reloads)

Tags: javascript, php, html, host

I do have a website that calls a javascript file stored somewhere else. I want that to only 10% of the visitors(or in other words...the script should work one time if you keep refreshing the page nearly every ten times)

I was thinking something like this:
I create an empty JS file.In the same place where i created it, I create another php file whose function is that once every ten times,it stores the code(the one i want to use) inside the js file.

Is that even possible? Forgive me if what i'm saying might sound weird to you but I'm a beginner into this kind of thing!

Thank You!

Comment: Just keep a counter on the server, either a file or in a DB somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Just use random, it will be pseudo accurate for once every 10 times.

```
if( Math.floor(Math.random()*10)==4 )
{
    //do your script or function call
}
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var trials = {};

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) trials[i] = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++) trials[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)]++;   
document.write(JSON.stringify(trials));
console.log(trials);
```

Or in PHP

```
<?php
    if( rand(1,10) == 4 ) { 
        echo '<script src="yourfile.js"></script>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but i guess i'm missing something here...
Do i have to put this conditional inside my js file or before calling js in my site?!

Comment: @JCoel - It wasn't clear exactly how you were referencing the file. If you have server side code available, it would be best to simply do this prior to writing to the response stream, and only write the `<script>` include when the condition was true.

Comment: is it any way possible to contact you in private?